# A show where the opening ends with the name written on gears and there are possibly some humans standing on them. The show is magic medieval

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

[image: looking something like that]

I've been searching for that show for about 7 years and I just cant find it. It is cartoon or anime. The setting is medieval and with some magic I think.[image: example of the setting of the show]

Comment: Does the picture relate to the story, or is it just a generic medieval village?

Comment: The show plays in a town similar to this picture. I would say the town is similar to the harry potter city. The gears picture is similar to the gears in that logo from the show.

Comment: What's "the harry potter city"? The only city I recall appearing in *Harry Potter* is London.

Comment: Hogsmeade? Diagon Alley?

Comment: How was the anime style? Were there robots in it from the gears thing? Could it be [Kinght's and Magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEwbSuKl8qM) ?

Comment: The description you gave kinda matches with [Steins;Gate](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steins;Gate) , Name of the show written inside gears, 7 years ago ( Steins;Gate is a 2011 anime, 9 years ago so it's close)

Comment: @Noblesse while it's also the first title that comes to my mind for "title in gears", the setting is far from medieval (it's current/near-future Japan). And whether if sci-fi's "time travel" is considered as magic...

Comment: Also, you stated that you have been searching for 7 years, but do you remember when (what year) did you watch it? Do you remember the language?